# Password protected SMS app for iPhone

Tags: security, iphone-app

The [Signal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.thoughtcrime.securesms&hl=en) app on Android has its own password control, so you hand out your unlocked phone to a friend without giving them access to your SMSs.

But https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-iOS/issues/738 indicates this is not part of iPhone Signal (on purpose).

Is there an alternative app that can password protect your unencrypted SMSs (preferably like Signal on Android)?

As the app is going to be used on company phones, jailbreaking is not an option.